# CSS rule inexplicably not being applied

Tags: html, css, list

I have a template I am modifying. It links to a stylesheet that the following code to manipulate unordered lists.

```
ul {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 40px 16px 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

I have a separate style sheet that has the following:

```
.featured_list ul {float: none; list-style: circle; list-style-position: inside;}
.featured_list li {margin: 5px;}
```

In my HTML code I reference my class like this

```
<ul class="featured_list">
```

Can anyone please tell me why my list is still set to float left tag? Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try your browser's DOM inspector? It'll show what rules are being applied to an element, where the rules come from, and which rules were overriden by later ones. We can't really help you, since you haven't provided enough html/css context to figure this out.

Comment: I guess you want `ul.featured_list`, not `.featured_list ul`.

Comment: Remove the ul from the .featured_list and if that doesnt work change `float: none;` to `float: none !important;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want this:

```
ul.featured_list
```

That is a `ul` with the class `featured_list`.  Your selector is for a `ul` **contained within** an element with class `featured_list`.

Answer (score 1):

For this markup

```
<ul class="featured_list">
```

you should be selecting it as

```
ul.featured_list {
styles here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you are writing your selector for unordered list as:

```
.featured_list ul{float:none; list-style:circle; list-style-position:inside;}
```

This will try to find all `ul` elements which are child elements of element with class `featured_list`. Instead of this you can directly use the class name to apply the style to the list as:

```
.featured_list {float:none; list-style:circle; list-style-position:inside;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qx8o4dee/)**:

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change the CSS file, then you want to wrap the ul with `.featured_list`:

```
<div class="featured_list">
    <ul>...</ul>
</div>
```

If you can change the stylesheet, then you need to change the styles to:

```
ul.featured_list {}
```